# Extracting substring with alternatives using regex in Python

Tags: python, regex

I tried looking for previous posts but couldn't find anything that matches exactly what I'm looking for so here goes.

I'm trying to parse through strings in a dataframe and capture a certain substring (year) if a match is found. The formatting can vary a lot and I figured out a non-elegant way to get it done but I wonder if there is a better way.

Strings can looks like this

```
Random Text 31.12.2020
1.1. -31.12.2020
010120-311220
31.12.2020
1.1.2020-31.12.2020 -
1.1.2019 - 31.12.2019
1.1. . . 31.12.2019 -
1.1.2019 - -31.12.2019
010120-311220 other random words
```

I'm looking to find the year, currently by finding the last date and its' year.
Current regex is `.+3112(\d{2,4})|.+31\.12\.(\d{2,4})` where

it would return **20 in group 1** for `010120-311220`,
and it would return **2020 in group 2** for `1.1.2020-31.12.2020 -`.

The problem is I cannot know beforehand which group the match will belong to, as in the first example group 2 doesn't exist and in the second example group 1 will return None when using `re.match(regexPattern, stringOfInterest)`. Therefore I couldn't access the value by naively using `.group(1)` on the match object, as sometimes the value would be in `.group(2)`.

Best I've come up so far is naming the groups with `(?P<groupName>\d{2,4)` and checking for Nones

```
def getYear(stringOfInterest):
    regexPattern = '(^|.+)3112(?P<firstMatchType>\d{2,4})|(^|.+)31\.12\.(?P<secondMatchType>\d{2,4})'
    matchObject = re.match(regexPattern, stringOfInterest)
    if matchObject is not None:
        matchDict = matchObject.groupdict()
        if matchDict['firstMatchType'] is not None:
            return matchDict['firstMatchType']
        else:
            return matchDict['secondMatchType']
    return None

import re
df['year'] = df['text'].apply(getYear)
```

And while this works it intuitively seems like a stupid way to do it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like all your years are from the XXI<sup>st</sup> century. In this case, all you need is

```py
df['year'] = '20' + df['text'].str.extract(r'.*31\.?12\.?(?:\d{2})?(\d{2})', expand=False)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rQSnYH/1). *Details*:

- `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `31\.?12\.?` - `31`, an optional `.`, `12`, and an optional `.` char
- `(?:\d{2})?` - an optional sequence of two digits
- `(\d{2})` - Group 1: two last digits of the year.

See a Pandas test:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'text': ['Random Text 31.12.2020','1.1. -31.12.2020','010120-311220','31.12.2020','1.1.2020-31.12.2020 -','1.1.2019 - 31.12.2019','1.1. . . 31.12.2019 -','1.1.2019 - -31.12.2019','010120-311220 other random words']})
df['year'] = '20' + df['text'].str.extract(r'.*31\.?12\.?(?:\d{2})?(\d{2})', expand=False)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
                               text  year
0            Random Text 31.12.2020  2020
1                  1.1. -31.12.2020  2020
2                     010120-311220  2020
3                        31.12.2020  2020
4             1.1.2020-31.12.2020 -  2020
5             1.1.2019 - 31.12.2019  2019
6             1.1. . . 31.12.2019 -  2019
7            1.1.2019 - -31.12.2019  2019
8  010120-311220 other random words  2020
```

Answer (score 0):

We can try using `re.findall` here against your input list, with a regex alternation covering both variants:

```py
inp = ["Random Text 31.12.2020", "1.1. -31.12.2020", "010120-311220", "31.12.2020", "1.1.2020-31.12.2020 -", "1.1.2019 - 31.12.2019", "1.1. . . 31.12.2019 -", "1.1.2019 - -31.12.2019", "010120-311220 other random words"]
output = [re.findall(r'\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.(\d{4})|\d{4}(\d{2})', x)[-1] for x in inp]
output = [x[0] if x[0] else x[1] for x in output]
print(output)  # ['2020', '2020', '20', '2020', '2020', '2019', '2019', '2019', '20']
```

The strategy here is to match either of the two date variants.  We retain the last match for each input.  Then, we use a list comprehension to find the non empty value.  Note that there are two capture groups, so only one will ever match.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex can be factorized a lot by grouping just the alternation of the beginning of the date; this removes the need to check for two groups:

```py
regexPattern = r'(?:^|.+)(?:3112|31\.12\.)(?P<year>\d{2,4})'
```

Once the group is extracted, it can be normalized into a proper four-digit year:

```py
if matchObject is not None:
    return ('20' + matchObject.group('year'))[-4:]
```

All in all, we get:

```py
import re

def getYear(stringOfInterest):
    regexPattern = r'(?:^|.+)(?:3112|31\.12\.)(?P<year>\d{2,4})'
    matchObject = re.match(regexPattern, stringOfInterest)
    if matchObject is not None:
        return ('20' + matchObject.group('year'))[-4:]
    return None

df['year'] = df['text'].apply(getYear)
```

Answer (score 0):

this is my approach to your problem, maybe it would be useful

```py
import re
string = '''
Random Text 31.12.2020
1.1. -31.12.2022
010120-311220
31.12.2020
1.1.2020-31.12.2018 -
1.1.2019 - 31.12.2019
1.1. . . 31.12.2019 -
1.1.2019 - -31.12.2019
010120-311220 other random words'''
pattern = r'\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.(\d{4})|\d{4}(\d{2})'
matches = re.findall(pattern, string)
print("1) ", matches)

# convert tuple to list
match_array = [i for sub in matches for i in sub]
print(match_array)

#Remove multiple empty spaces from string List
res = [element for element in match_array if element.strip()]
print(res)
```